# Working with Particles as a Game Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a Liquid in Unity that Can be worked with and have functions. I am trying to make something more like Pouring water from a bottle to an empty cup where the water in the Bottle Decreases and the cup start to have water. I tried working with particle system but I do not seem to have control of the particles itself like for example when a particle collide with another particle they form a bigger particle and when an Event happens other functions to apply to them.

The game intends to be for phone platforms. I will be working with pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to use particles for the water pouring effect.  However, to achieve the cup filling up with water you will have to use some trickery.  The water itself will have to be a plane or cube which rises or grows in size at a set interval while water is pouring or when particles collide with it.  Personally I would just do a set interval, especially since it's for mobile, as collision detection on that level is expensive.

There is no way to script a particle system on the individual particle level (or form new ones).  Particles are meant to be emitted and destroyed as quickly as possible.  Having them form a part of the permanent scene is not a viable option for performance reasons.

Comment: makes Scene, I just figured out that what I need cannot be achieved through Phone GPU and it will need a High end PC to achieve that.

Yet I wonder how to make a Liquid effect when Motion applies to the cup that have the filled plane with water ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with that, but it's not going to be easy. Probably your best bet would be buying a plugin on the asset store if possible.